# Visual Studio Database Project SQLCMD Variable Undefined For View Definition

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to create a database project with two databases that target SQL 2012. For this question I'll call the two databases 'DatabaseOne' and 'DatabaseTwo'.  In 'DatabaseTwo', I setup a database reference to 'DatabaseOne'.  I then create a view in 'DatabaseTwo' like this:

```
create view dbo.Test

as

select 
    ColumnOne 
from [$(DatabaseOne)].dbo.TestTable
```

I then get these errors in visual studio for the view creation:

```
Error       SQL71561: View: [dbo].[Test] has an unresolved reference to object [$(DatabaseOne)].[dbo].[TestTable].[ColumnOne].

Error       SQL71561: Computed Column: [dbo].[Test].[ColumnOne] has an unresolved reference to object [$(DatabaseOne)].[dbo].[TestTable].[ColumnOne].

Error       SQL71561: View: [dbo].[Test] has an unresolved reference to object [$(DatabaseOne)].[dbo].[TestTable].
```

If I leave everything the same, but change the create statement to be a procedure instead of a view, as shown below, the reference errors go away:

```
create procedure dbo.Test
as
select 
    ColumnOne 
from [$(DatabaseOne)].dbo.TestTable
```

Why does the command variable '$DatabaseOne' trigger errors for a view definition, but does not trigger errors for a procedure definition?

Comment: What happens when you actually execute your stored procedure? Do you get an error message similar to `Invalid object name '$(DatabaseOne).dbo.TestTable'`?

Comment: you can't have 3 part names in SSDT normally. I suggest you to create synonym for [$(DatabaseOne)].dbo.TestTable and then reference 2 part name synonym from your procedure. You must add DatabaseOne database reference as well.